# Is there a way to query my database so that blank values are skipped?

Tags: mysql

My current script pulls a value from the database, explodes the location and feeds it into google's geocoding API.

However, some organizations (for which I am pulling locations) are blank.  For Example I'll have

```
Org#1 Alabama
Org#2 Kentucky
Org#3 
Org#4 California
```

I know I can use if/else statements to filter out empty entries, but I want to know if there is a way to do this from my database query, so that extra scripting time isn't wasted just filtering out empty entries.

My current query looks like:

```
$sql = "SELECT Name As org FROM Orgs WHERE Org=".$Org; // get organization that matches org ID
 $org = sql_return_one_number($db_connection, $sql); // magic
   $orgrep = str_replace(" ", "+", $org); //remove all spaces and add a + sign for google API purposes 
$latlong = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$orgrep&sensor=false&key=KEY"); // pass info to google
$output=json_decode($latlong); //store it
 $status=$output->status;
```

Comment: Does all your results come from db with that 'Org#_' ?

Comment: Yes, The Org# or Org ID is a numerical identifier for all of our organizations. 

The Org ID is used in conjunction with a counter and the max # of organizations so that the script will start back over at Org#1 when it reaches the last Org.

Comment: Can't you just and a "and Org<>''" to your SQL?

Answer (score 2):

You would use a `where` clause, something like:

```
where name is not null
where name <> ''
where name <> '' and name is not null
where name is like 'Org#%' and name is not like 'Org#% %'
```

It is unclear what you mean by "blank".  The first works if blanks are `NULL`, the second if an empty string, the third if `NULL` or an empty string, and the forth if the name starts with `Org#'

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add `AND location NOT NULL` or `AND location <> ''` (depending on whether the field is null or just empty) to your query.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add another condition to the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT Name AS org
FROM Orgs
WHERE Org = ?
AND Name != ''
```

Of if by blank, you mean `NULL`:

```
SELECT Name AS org
FROM Orgs
WHERE Org = ?
AND Name IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this a couple different ways.  Either add more clauses to your query or check the $orgrep before passing it to google.

```
SELECT Name AS org FROM Orgs WHERE Org=? AND (Name IS NOT NULL OR Name != '')
```

OR

```
$sql = "SELECT Name As org FROM Orgs WHERE Org=".$Org; // get organization that matches org ID
$org = sql_return_one_number($db_connection, $sql); // magic
$orgrep = str_replace(" ", "+", $org); //remove all spaces and add a + sign for google API purposes 
if (!empty($orgrep)) {
    $latlong = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$orgrep&sensor=false&key=KEY"); // pass info to google
    $output=json_decode($latlong); //store it
    $status=$output->status;
}
```